# Make tomcat redirect to another server with the same domain

Tags: apache, tomcat, dns, system-administration

I have a domain name and a tomcat server so when I deploy an application on it, this is accesible via my.domain.com/MyApp and everything is fine.

The problem is that I have some applications I can't deploy on my tomcat server and i think i'll have to make another tomcat server to deploy them and when I type my.domain.com/MyNEWApp I want to be redirected to the new server but i don't know how to do it or if there is a better solution for my problem.

Comment: It makes no sense why you would need two tomcat servers in the same domain, anyway... here is a work around: create one app MyNEWApp in the older server which will only redirect to the new server, check http forwarding

Comment: @fmodos, having different Tomcats for different apps (different context roots) under the same domain is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: i need another tomcat server because the new apps i want to deploy were built using a different tomcat and java version... or there is a better solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your Tomcats behind a content-switching load balancer or a reverse proxy (e.g. Apache with mod_proxy, mod_jk or mod_cluster) and point the my.domain.com domain to the LB. Then on the LB, route traffic to respective Tomcats based on the context root.

Comment: +1 
...and I suggest mod_cluster, because unlike mod_jk or mod_proxy, mod_cluster will dynamically register contexts (deployed apps) on your tomcats, so you won't have to configure these contexts manually.